# Calculating line currents in three phase grid

Tags: power-supply, three-phase, ohms-law

My original network looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to find the line current $$l_{l, 1}$$ the red one at very top.

Here is what I have done:

I converted the delta impedance circuit in the right to star, my network looks like this now:

[image]

I apply the Millman theorem to find the voltage at the new star node:

$$S_v=\frac{\Sigma\frac{U_k}{Z_k}}{\Sigma\frac{1}{Z_k}}$$

And yes, I take the line impedance $$Zl_1$$ into account too.

Now I apply the Ohm's threom between the new node ( star at the right ) and the node just right behind the line impedance at top:

$$I_{l, 1} = \frac{S_v-U_1}{Zl_1+Z_1}$$

Well, my solution is not correct and I don't see where is my mistake.

I carried out all the calculations via a math software.

Comment: After your conversion of load to wye you can lump the line impedance into the wye, and then convert back to delta. Now you can easily calculate the line current (since the sources are ideal).  Pay attention to polarity.

Comment: @relayman357 Thanks for the solution, yeah I'll probably gonna try it, but what is wrong with my solution ?

Comment: What is the correct answer?  What numerical value did you get?